# Multiple SessionFactory in spring with hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to add two MySql database in spring project with hibernate. My question is that what should i use **multiple SessionFactory** or go ahead with **spring boot** and why?. If i use sessionfacotry then will be there any performance issue on project or is there any other alternative that i can use for adding multiple database?

Answer (score 0):

you can add several persistence units, obviously each PersitenceContext must have its own properties (url, user, password, driver,...), for example:

```html
@PersitenceContext("a")
private EntityManager emA;

@PersitenceContext("b")
private EntityManager emB;
```